Diagonalization/Eigenvalues of block matrices
Suppose I have two square $2^n \times 2^n$ matrices $A$ and $B$. Suppose furthermore that $A$ and $B$ are both symmetric matrices with real coefficients. Therefore their eigenvectors can be chosen to be orthonormal, and the matrices can be diagonalized with orthonormal matrices $R_a, R_b$:
$$A=R_A^{T} \Lambda_A R_A, $$
$$B=R_B^{T} \Lambda_B R_B.$$
Now I form the block-matrix $M$ of size $2^{n+1} \times 2^{n+1}$:
$$M=\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix} $$
Clearly, $M$ will also be symmetric with real coefficients, and so its eigenvectors can be chosen to be orthonormal, and $M$ can be diagonalized with another orthonormal matrix:
$$M=R_M^{T} \Lambda_M R_M.$$


Question: Is there any formula for the eigenvalues of $M$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$? Is there any formula for $R_M$ in terms of $R_A$ and $R_B?$


Attempt:
Taking inspiration from the $2 \times 2$ case we have
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a-b & 0 \\ 0 & a+b \end{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}= \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a-b & 0 \\ 0 & a+b \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
We can observe that this also works in block form:
$$M=\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix}= \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} -I & I \\ I & I \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A-B & 0 \\ 0 & A+B \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-I & I \\ I & I \end{pmatrix} $$
Now, this is not diagonalized yet, but the upper left and lower right block behave independently, and so:
$$M=\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix}= \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} -I & I \\ I & I \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} R^T_{A-B} & 0 \\ 0 & R^T_{A+B} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \Lambda_{A-B} & 0 \\ 0 & \Lambda_{A+B} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} R_{A-B} & 0 \\ 0 & R_{A+B} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-I & I \\ I & I \end{pmatrix} $$
Therefore, we could answer our original question if instead we answered:

Question: Is there any formula for the eigenvalues of $A+B$ and $A-B$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$? Is there any formula for $R_{A+B}$ and $R_{A-B}$ in terms of $R_A$ and $R_B?$


Context: Knowing how to do this would be useful for this problem: Sums of Matrices; 2-Color an $m \times k$ grid so that no $2 \times 2$ squares of the same color occur.

Interesting question, I'm not sure if this may help but perhaps you could double check the solution if you already have some examples.
What is given is $$ R_{A-B}^T\Lambda_{A-B}R_{A-B} = A-B $$ and we would like to find
$$
\begin{cases}
 eig(A-B) &= f(eig(A), eig(B)) \\
 R_{A-B} &= R_{A-B}(R_A, R_B)
\end{cases}.
$$
Begin with looking for the eigenvalues
$$
\begin{split}
(A-B)x = \lambda_{A-B}x \implies (A-\gamma\lambda_{A-B}I)x - (B+(1-\gamma)\lambda_{A-B}I)x = 0
\end{split},
$$
for some $\gamma$ such that $ 0 \leq \gamma \leq 1 $. Since $R_A$ and $R_B$ are square and orthonormal,
$$
 (A-\gamma\lambda_{A-B}I)x = R_A^T(\Lambda_A-\gamma\lambda_{A-B}I)R_Ax 
$$
and notice that $R_A^T(\Lambda_A-\gamma\lambda_{A-B}I)R_A$ has the same eigenvectors as $R_A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_A-\gamma\lambda_{A-B}I$. Therefore it is once again symmetric but it can't be guaranteed to have real coefficients. If it is degenerate such that its null space is not empty then find $x$ such that each term satisfies
$$
\begin{cases}
 (A-\gamma\lambda_{A-B}I)x &= 0 \\
 (B+(1-\gamma)\lambda_{A-B}I)x &= 0
\end{cases}.
$$
Notice that now it is just a system of equations for finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors. This gives
$$
\begin{cases}
 \lambda_A &= \gamma\lambda_{A-B} \\
 \lambda_B &= -(1-\gamma)\lambda_{A-B}
\end{cases}
$$
or
$$
\begin{cases}
 \lambda_{A-B} &= \lambda_A/\gamma \\
 \lambda_{A-B} &= -\lambda_B/(1-\gamma)
\end{cases}.
$$
The set of eigenvectors $R_{A-B}$ of $A-B$ is then the intersection of eigenvectors of $R_A$ and $R_B$. Then
$$
\begin{split}
 A-B = R_{A-B}^T\Lambda_{A-B}R_{A-B} &= \frac{1}{\gamma}R_{A-B}^T\Lambda_AR_{A-B} \\
&= -\frac{1}{1-\gamma}R_{A-B}^T\Lambda_BR_{A-B}
\end{split}
$$
so the columns of $R_{A-B}$ will be some combination of $R_A$ and $R_B$. To achieve this you could set up the block matrix
$$
R_{A-B} = 
\alpha
\begin{pmatrix}
R_A & 0 \\
0 & R_B 
\end{pmatrix}
$$ where $\alpha$ is a 2x2 block diagonal which represents which columns to select from $R_A$ and $R_B$ respectively.

The answers to both questions are ‘no’. Let
$$
A_1=\pmatrix{1\\ &0},\quad
A_2=\pmatrix{0\\ &1}\quad\text{and}\quad
B=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&1}.
$$
$A_1$ and $A_2$ have identical eigenvalues and identical eigenspaces, but $M_1=\pmatrix{A_1&B\\ B&A_1}$ and $M_2=\pmatrix{A_2&B\\ B&A_2}$ do not share any eigenvalue or eigenvector: the spectra of $M_1$ and $M_2$ are $\{-2,\,0,\,2-\sqrt{2},\,2+\sqrt{2}\}$ and $\{-1-\sqrt{2},\,-1+\sqrt{2},\,1,\,3\}$ respectively; the four one-dimensional eigenspaces of $M_1$ are the linear spans of the unit vectors
$$
\pmatrix{1/2\\ 1/2\\ -1/2\\ -1/2},\quad
\pmatrix{1/2\\ -1/2\\ -1/2\\ 1/2},\quad
\pmatrix{s\\ -r\\ s\\ -r},\quad
\pmatrix{r\\ s\\ r\\ s},
$$
where $r=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$ and $s=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$, while the four one-dimensional eigenapaces of $M_2$ are linear spans of the unit vectors
$$
\pmatrix{r\\ s\\ -r\\ -s},
\pmatrix{s\\ -r\\ -s\\ r},
\pmatrix{1/2\\ -1/2\\ 1/2\\ -1/2},
\pmatrix{1/2\\ 1/2\\ 1/2\\ 1/2}.
$$

+1 This dashes hopes of simple formula for $\Lambda_{A+B}$ in terms of $\Lambda_{A}$ and $\Lambda_{B},$ although hope might remain for a formula for  $\Lambda_{A+B}$ in terms of  $\Lambda_{A}, \Lambda_{B}, R_{A}$ and $R_{B}.$
